# VS 2010 beta 2 Web ReportViewer Bug?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

The report viewer doesn't seem to work in asp.net projects in VS 2010. You get the following error:

**Microsoft Jscript runtime error: ‘Microsoft’ is undefined**.

VS also breaks on the following line of javascript code:

**$create(Microsoft.Reporting.WebFormsClient.ReportViewer, {"_internalViewerId":"ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1_ctl03","id":"ctl00_MainContent_ReportViewer1"}, null, null);**

Steps to recreate problem:

- In Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 create a new asp.net project
- Drag a ScriptManager control on to default.aspx
- Drag a ReportViewer control on to default.aspx
- Build and run the project
- You then get the problem

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have a similar problem with winforms projects - updating to VS2010 breaks all the report viewer components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you download the latest patches to VS2010 RC? I was unable to reproduce this particular issue. It might have been fixed in RC.

You may also interested in couple of other bugs that I logged for VS2010 RC
http://blog.rajsoftware.com/post/VS2010-RC-bugs-2(two)-that-I-reported-in-MS-Connect.aspx